# Is there another way to get "fs" metric of node besides /stats/summary

Tags: kubernetes, metrics

We've been using `/stats/summary` to get `fs` metrics, which is like:

```
"fs": {
 "time": "2021-10-14T03:46:05Z",
 "availableBytes": 17989276262,
 "capacityBytes": 29845807308,
 "usedBytes": 5856531046,
 "inodesFree": 16799593,
 "inodes": 17347097,
 "inodesUsed": 57504
},
```

And due to this [Move away from kubelet stats/summary](https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/12792), we need to get the same data in another way.

We've tried `/metrics/cadvisor` and `/metrics/resources`, but were not successful to get `fs` data.
Also, it seems that CAdvisor will also be deprecated (in TBD+2 [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/68522))

We've been searching the net for possible solution but can't seem to find any.

Any ideas on how this can be done?
Or probably point us to the right direction or documentation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which Kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: Which exactly call / command are you making? How did you setup your Kubernetes cluster - some cloud provider solution or bare metal?

Comment: @MikolajS.  Kubernetes Version:  `client version = 1.20`  `server version = 1.21`    Which exactly call / command are you making:  `kubectl get --raw /api/v1/nodes/<node name>/proxy/stats/summary`    How did you setup your Kubernetes cluster:  `bare metal`

Comment: Is this call working properly now for you? I tested this call both on `v1.21` and `v.1.22` and it's working fine. Do you have any exact issue or you are just looking for replacement? For now, seems that Kubernetes team [is not ready with it](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/68522): >`[TBD] Propose out-of-tree replacements for kubelet monitoring endpoints
 [TBD] Deprecate the Summary API and cAdvisor prometheus endoints by adding and deprecating a --enable-container-monitoring-endpoints flag`.

Comment: State for November 2020 (main post edited, the issue is open). I was unable to find any more recent information.

Comment: /stats/summary is currently working on our end. However, due to the direction that it will be deprecated, we're looking for other ways to get the same information. Specifically the **fs** portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posted community wiki based on Github topic. Feel free to expand it.

---

Personally, I have not found any equivalent of this call (`/api/v1/nodes/<node name>/proxy/stats/summary`), and as it is still working and not deprecated in the Kubernetes newest versions ( `1.21` and `1.22`), I'd recommend just using it and wait for information about replacement from the Kubernetes team. Check below information:

Information from this [GitHub topic - # Reduce the set of metrics exposed by the kubelet  #68522](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/68522) (last edited: November 2020, issue open):

It seems that `/stats/summary/` does not have any replacement recommendation ready:

> [TBD] Propose out-of-tree replacements for kubelet monitoring endpoints

They will keep the Summary API for the next four versions counting from the version in which replacement will be implemented:

> [TBD+4] Remove the Summary API, cAdvisor prometheus metrics and remove the `--enable-container-monitoring-endpoints` flag.

---

In Kubernetes [`v1.23` changelog](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.23.md) there is no information about changing anything related to the Summary API.

I'd suggest observing and pinging Kubernetes developers directly in [this GitHub topic](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/68522) for more information.